# Wrong Value gets set?

Tags: android

I don't know what i do wrong but something doesn't quite work how intended.
I have a counter which gets increased by 1 everytime i click a button.
At the Endscreen i want to show the final "turnCounter" but it shows the weong number?!

Edit: The Problem was the turnCounter Variable was redefined in the class

Comment: Is the EndScreen a different activity? If so, you'll have to pass the value to that activity as an Extra in the Intent.

Comment: Yes it is but i declare turnCounter as public static in the MainActivity which all other Activity extend

Comment: Okay. So what actually happens? Do you get any value back? Are you always hitting the "else" in your comparison?

Comment: It seems to only happen when case 3 in my turn function is called.  Maybe the Problem is that i have 3 && conditions?